# Multiple tables for user login

Tags: cakephp, authentication

So, in my CakePHP app I have Administrators and Moderators (moderators are actually user profiles displayed on the frontend and have very limited access in the backend), while the administrators are controlling the moderators and their profile changes. I have separate tables for this (if it is the right way, I will merge them and build a standard login).

When a user goes to www.example.com/moderator, I want to authenticate only from the moderators table, add a variable to `$this->Auth->user()` like `'role' => 'moderator'` and redirect to www.example.com/moderators/view/moderator_id. When a user goes to www.example.com/administrator, I want administrator authentication and different redirect. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: No, I would say, that this does not sound like a good approach. Use roles and decide upon one single login where to redirect to. you should avoid unnecessary redirects. For role management you can use [tiny](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/).

Comment: Alright then, single table it is.

Comment: Usually a User model including roles directly or with a Role model as belongsTo relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a single table.

If you create a table, and you find yourself duplicating a lot (or in this case probably ALL) of the fields, that should be a BIG red flag that you probably need to re-think your table structure.

As many of the above comments pointed out, the "normal" way to do this is via `users` and `roles` tables.

```
users
 - id
 - username (or email)
 - password
 - role_id

role
 - id
 - name
```

Then, when a user logs in, you'll also have their associated Role information to use, which allows you to redirect to a specific location, or give or deny access to specific things based on that role...etc.

Comment: Did this already, it works fine now... I just wanted to know if there is a way to do it without modifying the database.

Comment: Gotcha - I just saw your comment: "if it is the right way, I will merge them and build a standard login" - sounded like you wanted to know the 'right' way.  Glad you got it all working.